# Crosstab wizard not showing columns to transpose

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that results in columns:

```
Location
AssetDesc
AssetType
AssetSubType
AttributeDesc
AssetAttributeValue
```

I'm trying to turn the AttrbuteDesc values into column headings with AssetAttributeValue column as their values. However when I'm in the crosstab query wizard the only available fields I can pick are:

```
Location
AssetDesc
AssetType
AssetSubType
```

Why is it not showing the AttributeDesc or AssetAttributeValue columns for me to pick from to pivot on?

The data in AttributeDesc has:

```
Manufacturer
Model #
Serial #
Stand Size (For "test")
Does Unit Have Iced Coffee/Ice Tea Retrofit
```

The data in AssetAttributeValue has:

```
Work Oasis
G-77
123456789
10 inch
NA
```

Comment: What is the data type for these two columns? If they're `Memo` then I think that's where your problem lies.

Comment: They are Long Text. Can you not crosstab on text data? I don't want to sum/count whatever I just need to make it more tabular in nation for reporting. Event still it doesn't show up in the first Available Fields section to pick from, which is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can crosstab on text but not long text (used to be called Memo).

Comment: That did it! Thanks.